# Issue with uploading file through API when ' in the name of a file

Tags: javascript

I have a react app which uploads files using the api to sharepoint. Now everything works fine, except if the name contains this symbol => '

The call of the api looks something like this:
filename = "File ' name.doxc";
.post(url + `/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('ListTitle')/items('1')/AttachmentFiles(FileName='${encodeURIComponent(filename)")`,

And the error is in the post call, basically like this...

```
"web/lists/getByTitle('ListTitle')/items('1')/AttachmentFiles/add(FileName="File ' name.docx")" is not valid
```

I tried differently to encode etc, but it does not work, how to make sure that I preseve ' and can pass through api call? Maybe replace by UTF code or something? Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

you can change the ' symbol to "  .

when the user submit a file (file, name, any input field) you should replace the ' symbol to " because the ' symbol makes a lot of problems in code especially in backend and databases.

example in C#:

```
string FileName=TheFileName.Replace("'","\"");
//the file name will be saved in FileName without any problems
```

I think if you replace the symbol everything will work fine.